# Smalltalk and IoC

Tags: inversion-of-control, smalltalk

I see a lot of IoC frameworks for .Net and Java.  Does anyone know why there are no equivalent frameworks for Smalltalk.  This is more a philosophy question than anything else.  I'm wondering if there is something in the Smalltalk way of doing things that precludes the necessity of having an IoC framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_view_controller) was invented on Smalltalk and is arguably the original [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) framework.  While somewhat more lightweight than its java counterparts, it has the basic concepts of a model holding the data, a view rendering the data in response to events propogated from a controller.

Less flippantly, Java is actually needs a lot of framework support to do a web application without excessive quantities of boilerplate code.  Smalltalk supports programming idioms such as [continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuations), which allow an author to pretend they are not really writing event driven code.  [Seaside](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seaside_(software)) works like this, giving the benefits of IoC with a somewhat more flexible development paradigm.

EDIT: MVC is a framework for UI's in Smalltalk (arguably it's not really a framework as such, but the class library has built in support for it).  It has the inversion of control property in that the view and model respond to events dispatched by the controller - the don't call us, we'll call you property.  Inversion of Control is a design pattern within frameworks that's used to reduce the need for extensive boilerplate in java applications.  In some definitions of an application framework, Inversion of Control is the main property that is viewed as distinguishing a framework from a library.

Comment: Nigel:  I was aware that MVC originated with Smalltalk.  What confuses me about this is that and IoC framework like Castle contains an MVC framework (MonoRail) and an IoC framework (Windsor) which suggests that they are different?

Comment: Language issue:  Delegates/Closures/Callbacks/EventHandling is so easy on a smalltalk platform, as to be unremarked upon. Because it's harder to achieve IoC on other platforms, and because it requires scaffolding (framework) code to implement well, and consistently, one might expect to see a requirement for such scaffolding code in Smalltalk. There isn't any such need. Because it's easy.

Answer (score 6):

Functions are first class citizens in smalltalk, so it is easy to have IoC without a framework.

Answer (score 4):

I think that IOC or the Dependency Injection pattern solves a problem that doesn't really exist in the Smalltalk environment.  Smalltalk is an untyped dynamic language and uses message passing to communicate.  This makes for objects that are loosely coupled by nature at the language level.  Any object can send a message to another object without regard to the type as long as it can process the message.  So, as you might guess changing dependencies at any given time is relatively easy and natural. Just have to decide where, when, and how you want to change the dependency.

Comment: "solves a problem that doesn't really exist in the Smalltalk" - *yes* Besides, Smalltalk programmers are kinder to kittens: http://www.flickr.com/photos/dafydd_ll_rees/4528702680/

Answer (score 2):

A few possible reasons for this.  One is that we haven't bothered to use the "IoC" qualifier, which is essentially redundant - since calling something a framework implies the inversion of control flow.

Another is that the Smalltalk language provides direct support for "IoC" flows - in the form of closures.  One result of programming with closures is that the flow of control as found in frameworks doesn't seem so starkly different as to evoke a sense of being "inverted" from a "normal" sense of flow; rather, with closures, the flow of control is flipping back and forth between these two perspectives all of the time, and everywhere.  Even within single statements.

A third reason, perhaps, is that, even without closures, the "inversion of control" being described is not uniquely associated with frameworks - the same flows are found in most forms of code that involve I/O.

Fourth, Smalltalkers probably use these sorts of flows even more than others, as we lean more heavily on the notions of objects and the messages sent between them than on the notions of structures and the calling of member functions.  In the absense of closures, these two views are equivalent, and interchangeable, but the addition of closures changes the result - the sense of control flow in use is one of the effects.

Finally, one might even think about describing the REPL style of control flow as a "simpler", but "inverted" sense of the "normal" flow, normal in the sense that it is used nearly everywhere else.

In summary, the same sorts of frameworks exist for Smalltalk.
We describe them a bit differently is all.
The difference is, at least in part, due to the presence and utilization
of closures in Smalltalk, which many other environments do not yet provide --
-- notably C++, C#, and Java.

Answer (score 2):

In Java a Dependency is created when you write
something like

MyClass32 temp  = this.theThing();

Now your code DEPENDS on the class MyClass32 
being around. Your code will not work 
without it. Any change in that class can
make your code uncompilable, requiring a 
lot of extra changes in your code, which
may require further code-changes in class
that depend on yours. Lots of extra work.

In Smalltalk you would write
  temp  :=  self theThing;

Your code will work no matter what is returned
by #getTheThing.  Your code is not dependent
on the class MyClass32 being around.  Your only
dependency is that 'temp' must understand whatever
messages you send to it.

So in a sense the purpose of Dependency Injection
Frameworks is to make a statically typed language
like Java work more like  a dy7namically typed one.

That said, there is a DESIGN PATTERN I've often
followed in Smalltalk: Create a class-method like 
MyClass that  returns SOME class. It need not have
the NAME 'MyCLass'. It could be one of several 
classes, returning a different class at night. 
This pattern is present in the Smalltalk MVC, 
where View-classes have the method #defaultControllerClass, 
which is  typically redefined by subclasses.